# Connect an Azure App Registration to Azure SQL Database via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, adal

Need a Powershell script to run on-prem that will login into an Azure SQL database as an Azure AD App Registration.  I am able to acquire an access token for the App Registration, but I get an error when I attempt to login to the database with it:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'NT  AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

I have created the user and applied grants inside the target database.

```sql
CREATE USER [App Reg Dave Test] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [App Reg Dave Test];
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [App Reg Dave Test];
```

I'm not sure it's necessary, but I have also granted api permissions to the App registration for SQL Database User_Impersonation and App_Impersonation.  Here is a sample of my PS code.  It's failing on the $connection.open() command.

```bsh
#-- Intall ADAL.ps
# Import-Module ADAL.PS

#-----------------------------------
#--  Get Token for App Registration
#-----------------------------------

$tenantId = "448b9f7b-9e69-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
$resourceUrl = "api://123a7216-7b20-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
$clientId = "123a7216-7b20-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "X87ZK@NPw=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzx/-" -AsPlainText -Force
$response = Get-ADALToken -Authority $authority -Resource $resourceUrl -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $secret
$token = $response.AccessToken

#-----------------------------------
#--  Connect to DB
#-----------------------------------

$sqlServerUrl = "dave-sqls2.database.windows.net"
$database = "advworks"
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:$sqlServerUrl,1433;Initial Catalog=$database;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

# Add AAD generated token to SQL connection token
$connection.AccessToken = $response.AccessToken

$connection  #-- Output connection object for debugging.

$query = "SELECT @@Servername, @@Version"
$command = New-Object -Type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
$connection.Close()
$dataSet.Tables
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PowerShell script you provide, you use the wrong `resourceUrl`. Please update the resource url as `https://database.windows.net/`. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Azure-AD-Service-Principal-authentication-to-SQL-DB-Code-Sample/ba-p/481467).

The detailed steps are as below.
1. Create service principal

```
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "[Enter SPN Password]" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "[Enter name for Application]" -HomePage "https://www.contoso.com/sqldb-spn" -IdentifierUris "https://www.contoso.com/sqldb-spn" -Password $SecureStringPassword -OutVariable app
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

2. Use Azure AD admin to login Azure SQL via SSMS. Then run the following command

```
CREATE USER [your app name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [App Reg Dave Test];
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [App Reg Dave Test];
```

3. Get Access token

```
$tenantId = "your tenant id"
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/authorize"
$resourceUrl = "https://database.windows.net/"
$clientId = "your application id"
$secret=ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$response = Get-ADALToken -Authority $authority -Resource $resourceUrl -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $secret
$token = $response.AccessToken
```

4 Connect SQL

```
$sqlServerUrl = "<your server name>.database.windows.net"
$database = "master"
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:$sqlServerUrl,1433;Initial Catalog=$database;Connect Timeout=30"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.AccessToken = $response.AccessToken
$connection.Open()

$query="SELECT name, database_id, create_date  FROM sys.databases ; "
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)   
$Result = $command.ExecuteScalar()
$Result
$connection.Close()
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason i get this error on conn.open
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'."